# Can't connect to wifi network - Debian

Tags: debian, wifi

I have problems with wifi network - I can see list of SSIDs but can't connect to anyone. Wifi adapter:

```
 - Bus 007 Device 003: ID 148f:3070
   Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

Drivers:

System version:

```
Linux debian 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3 (2017-12-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Chipset drivers works (can see SSID). What can I do more to solve this problem? 
Thanks for any response.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
 - 05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: 
Broadcom Limited NetXtreme
   BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1681] (rev 10)   Subsystem: Dell
   NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1028:0293]  Kernel driver in
   use: tg3     Kernel modules: tg3
```

I post result of `lsmod | grep rt2`:

```
rt2800usb              28672  0 
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt2800usb 
rt2800lib              94208  1 rt2800usb 
rt2x00lib              53248  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              671744  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb 
cfg80211              589824  2rt2x00lib,mac80211 
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib 
usbcore               249856 usbhid,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,ehci_hcd,uhci_hcd,usblp,ehci_pci
```

Comment: It's posted informations about ethernet card.

Comment: @A.B I know - I have installed package wpasupplicant.

Comment: I have one of those usb wifi chipsets, and while it is detected pretty well, it is fairly buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Debian. Please read the *official Debian documentation* in the Debian Wiki as **[found here](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb).**

Your card is listed under "supported devices", so it should work:

> USB: 148F:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter

Comment: I know - specially I bought card with Debian compatible chipset.I have downloaded drivers from you link earlier. Thanks for response.